# Android Firebase Get Post id from post element

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database:

[image]

I want to get post id from post element.

I know authorId, createdDate, createdDateText and title, but I want to get post id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with firebase query like bellow,

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
        query.orderByChild("title").equalTo("test");//Here replace title with your key which you want and replace test with value throw which search
        //query.orderByChild("title").equalTo("test").limitToFirst(1); //If you want to only one value
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //you get here the list of post from  DB 
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String postId = child.getKey(); //Post Id
                        Logger.print("postId");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: If there are 2 posts with the same title, this will return both of them. But OP only wants one.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer for Both comment please check.

Answer (score 0):

try final String postId = getRef(position).getKey();